# Usage of "-timestamp now" in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, timestamp

I'm new to ffmpeg and I'd like to ask if anyone know how to use "-timestamp now" in ffmpeg.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293853/how-to-use-ffmpeg-timestamp-syntax said that the timestamp stores in the output file. However I haven't found it or seen it. And there is no tutorial or information about, how could we get the timestamp from the recieving side or how could we use the timestamp. So does anyone have any clues on that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What `-timestamp now` does is forward the current time as the `creation time` to the muxer of the output file. The output muxer *may* then write it as creation time or origination time or similar, if it supports it. Major formats like MOV / MP4 / Matroska do.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! If there is a way that I can access the time without using muxer? Because I use ffmepg for video streaming and I really need the timestamp  to calcluate the time lag on the receving side.

Comment: All media output in ffmpeg goes through a muxer. If you're streaming over RTMP, it's the FLV muxer, which will have an AMF string with key `creation_time`